Target both .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 8.0 in SDK project?
I have an application that is an addin to another larger application developed by another company (i.e. I have no control over the parent application).  The parent application is updating to .NET 8.0 for their next release but currently is on .NET Framework 4.8.  I will need to support this new version but continue supporting old versions for a few years.  We have traditionally done this with conditional references in the csproj file.  We are now "moving up" to the new SDK project format.  I'm trying to get this to work but I'm having trouble crossing the different targets.
I have set up a basic sample for testing by creating a new solution that just has 2 default projects in it with the basic modifications for multi-targeting.  Here is the .csproj file content for the referenced library:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net48;net8.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
    <Configurations>Release2024;Release2025</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release2025'">
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <OutputPath>..\Build 2025\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;r2025</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release2024'">
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <OutputPath>..\Build 2024\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;r2024</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

And here is for the 'top level' project that references that one:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net48;net8.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
    <Configurations>Release2024;Release2025</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release2025'">
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <OutputPath>..\Build 2025\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;r2025</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release2024'">
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <OutputPath>..\Build 2024\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;r2024</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TestReferenced\TestReferenced.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I then have solution configs that are the same name.  The idea is that when I build 'Release2024' everything targets 4.8 and when I build 'Release2025' everything targets 8.0.  However, when I try to build Release2025 it tells me:

'..\TestReferenced\TestReferenced.csproj' targets 'net8.0-windows'. It
cannot be referenced by a project that targets
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.8'. TestLibrary C:\Program Files\Microsoft
Visual
Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   1860

I know that TestReferenced has the option to reference 4.8, but for that configuration it should target 8.0...
Is there any way to get it to target this way and build correctly?
EDIT
I should also mention that I have WPF components in my project that I will need to use.

I’d target .net standard

What do you mean by that?  I need to target framework 4.8 for the older versions and .NET 8.0 for the new version...

.net standard is a common subset of both

Ok thank you, I was only vaguely aware of standard as I haven't had to use it before but doing research on it now and will try it out...

Ok so after more research, I don't think this will work.  I need to use WPF (which I realize is not in the original question but I'll add it after this).  From what I can see WPF is not included in .NET standard.

For anyone else coming along I did end up getting this working.  I just set the initial TargeFramework to 8.0 and reset that based on the conditions, something like this (removed extra properties to highlight the differences):
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Release2024;Release2025</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release2025'">
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release2024'">
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TestReferenced\TestReferenced.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

This seems to allow it to see only the relevant framework for the build configuration and use that one and all seems to work as expected.

You wouldn’t happen to be upgrading for Revit would you? If so, I am doing this same thing.
For me the trouble with your final solution is that it builds fine in VS (when the VS UI refreshes the obj resources on the platform-combobox-change event), but using dotnet CLI, it initializes incorrectly and cannot find the correct TargetFramework for earlier builds on net481.
Tried dotnet refresh, but didn’t seem to work… still looking for a good solution.‍♂️

I am...  Yes in the UI you need to change to the right config and then let it get itself updated and then build.  I haven't tried cli builds so don't now about that.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
